# How to advance filter on multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count the unique values of a column therefor I first used a autofilter to get the correct rows that I want to advanced filter.

The result I've assigned to a range using

```
intersect(Used.range,range.specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

This gave me a range say (B10:B20, B75) so it's actually 2 ranges B10:B20 and B75. Therefor I cannot directly apply a advancedfilter on it. Does someone know how to do achieve this?

I've thought of splitting the range into two seperates but then I cannot count the unique values correctly, I'll get a count of one range and a count of the other but it's possible that they have the same values. I've also thought to put the values in a array, but it's not a very efficient way to do it I think.

Thanks.

Comment: I've used the inefficient way check if exist in array if not put in array. Then array.count for the count. Not a nice solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Filter is not required if you only need a count of the filtered uniques.

Consider:

```
Sub Xepos()
    Dim N As Long, c As Collection
    Dim colid As String, r As Range
    colid = "A"
    Set c = New Collection
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, colid).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To N
        Set r = Cells(i, colid)
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            v = r.Text
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox c.Count
End Sub
```

This assumes that the column is column **A** and there is a header cell in **A1**

Comment: Too bad this is not what I'm looking for, but I've filtered it not for the unique values but to get the rows which can apply for the advanced filter.